# How to set compiler in waf

Tags: python, waf

I'm trying to compile 3rd party software which uses waf as the build tool.  I run into problems immediately.

```
> python waf configure --prefix=install 
Checking for program 'g++, c++'          : CC 
Could not determine the compiler version ['CC', '-dM', '-E', '-']
```

The config.log file says (with some extra crap deleted):

```
Checking for program 'g++, c++'
CC
['CC', '-dM', '-E', '-']
out: No supported cpu target is set, CRAY_CPU_TARGET=x86-64 will be used.
Load a valid targeting module or set CRAY_CPU_TARGET

err: CC-2130 crayc++: WARNING in command line
  The "-d" commandline option is unsupported.
CC-2289 crayc++: ERROR in command line
  Invalid characters after option '-d' in command line item '-dM'.
CC-2107 crayc++: ERROR in command line
  No valid filenames are specified on the command line.
```

I don't know how to debug waf scripts. Does anyone have any suggestions?  I guess that I have to tell waf to use gcc (or c++) as the compiler, but I can't even figure out how to tell waf to do that.  waf has an argument --check-cxx-compiler, but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Where is your C++ compiler?

Comment: How did you check for the g++? By `python waf configure --check-cxx-compiler=gxx`? If so, it should have worked.

Comment: Can you include your `configure` function?